# Specify Makefile

Tags: vimrc

I am pretty new to Vim and I need some help with work-flow developing in C++.

Currently, I am using Sublime Text as my primary editor for the following work-flow:

Lets say I am working on RingBuffer class, for which I have

- `ring_buffer.h`
- `ring_buffer.cpp`
- `unittest\ring_buffer_mock.h`
- `unittest\ring_buffer_test.cpp`
- and `unittest\ring_buffer.makefile`.

Each makefile has its own set of dependencies.  Sublime Text allows you to add a build system, which runs a shell command defined by user in project file, and parses the output.  To test the Ring Buffer, I go to `menu`->`tools`->`BuildSystem`->`RingBuffer`.  So here is the question

1. Can you recommend a good work-flow in VIM?
2. Is it possible in local `.vimrc` to specify makefile, such as `ring_buffer.makefile`?

EDIT! First off, `set makeprg=make\ -f\ ring_buffer.makefile` works well, but it does not offer any automation.  So I am going to ask a second question which can be found here:

[Determining makefile based on source file name](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4503/determining-makefile-based-on-source-file-name)

Comment: 1. One of tons articles: http://www.alexeyshmalko.com/2014/using-vim-as-c-cpp-ide/
2. `set makeprg=make\ -f\ ring_buffer.makefile`

Comment: What is the purpose of the '\' char after each option?

Comment: `\ ` is a escaped space symbol. See `:he makeprg` for examples and explanations.

Comment: Thank you.  Actually I did read the help, but being so new to VIM, it is hard to understand.  Things that you advanced users take for granted are sometimes a mystery to a beginner like me.

Comment: If I wanted to add error window `:copen`, I tried the follwoing: `set makeprg=make\ -f\ ring_buffer.makefile | copen`, but it still goes to the terminal.  Any way to prevent it from flashing the terminal?

Comment: Note: `:make` executes make program which you set with `set makeprg` and opens window with errors. `:!make` fires up your shell and make inside it. You shouldn't pipes outputs to copen with `set makeprg`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26587/discussion-between-user1135541-and-alex-kroll).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about C++ development, but in regard to your questions about good workflows and granular control with makefiles I'd tell you to look no further than tpope's [vim-dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch).

With this plugin you can use `:Make` to start an asynchronous build in the foreground (for longer build tasks you can append a `!` to start it in the background instead). Just this command makes this plugin a must-have if you work with makefiles.

But there is more. Another cool command provided is `:Dispatch`, which might address a couple of your requests. It's basically like `:Make` but provides a bit more control:

```
:Dispatch picks a compiler by looking for either
CompilerSet makeprg={program}\ [arguments] or
CompilerSet makeprg={program} in compiler plugins.
To force a given {program} to use a given {compiler},
create ~/.vim/after/compiler/{compiler}.vim and add to
it a line like the following:

" CompilerSet makeprg={program}
```

You can have even more control by setting `g:dispatch_compilers` in your `vimrc`. This option takes a dictionary where the keys are commands you can call after `:Dispatch` and compiler plugins are the values:

```
let g:dispatch_compilers = {
    \ 'latex': 'tex',
    \ 'bundle exec': ''}
```

Make sure to read through the docs, there's definitely more to it.