# Determining makefile based on source file name

Tags: makeprg

For current source file with the following name pattern: `xxx_test.cpp` how do you execute make file with the following patter `xxx.makefile`.  I tried using

```
set makeprg=make\ -f\ fnameescape(substitute(expand("%"),"_test.cpp$",".makefile","")))
```

but it gives me the following output:

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `make -f fnameescape(substitute(expand(  2>&1| tee /tmp/user/1000/v98gzpR/261'
```

I am new to VIM, I tried to parse the vim help files, but cannot find an answer on how to have VIM execute the substitution.

EDIT:  The right answer is presented by Sato Katsura here:  [Why is make running against a wrong file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4841/why-is-make-running-against-a-wrong-file/4842#4842)

Thanks...

Comment: I see a trailing `)` in your setting, is that related to the issue ? I also have the following error : `zsh:1: bad pattern: fnameescape(substitute(expand(  2`

Comment: "set" doesn't evaluate the right-hand side of the = as vimscript, it just treats it as a string; your shell is not going to understand what "fnameescape(...)" is. Using "let" with string concatenation as in Sato's answer should work though, as it will evalute the right-hand side as vimscript.

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to forget about wrapping your mind around `set` syntax, and use `let` instead:

```
let &makeprg = 'make -f ' . fnameescape(substitute(expand('%'), '\m_test\.cpp$', '.makefile', ''))
```

See `:help :let-&` for details.

Comment: Works great, but is there a way to prevent vi from going to console, just let the list of errors window display the errors?

Comment: @user1135541 Not reliably.  You can however run `system()` followed by `cgetexpr` instead of `make`.

Comment: Strange, all of a sudden, I am getting this error `[No write since last change]
/home/sporty/.vimrc:1: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop.

Press ENTER or type command to continue
`

Comment: You seem to be running `make` against your `vimrc`.  Perhaps do the above dance with `makeprg` only for the relevant files?

Comment: Hmm, so I am in VIM, the current file is the `ring_buffer_test.cpp`.  Should the VIM not replace `%` with `ring_buffer_test.cpp` and do the substitution?  Why is it running against some random file?  In fact it did run it against some other source file.

Comment: Does not work most of the time...