# Why is make running against a wrong file?

Tags: vimrc, makeprg

I am trying to get VIM to run the right makefile for a specific source file.  For example, if the current file is `ui8_c_buff_test.cpp` and if I use the `makeprg` configuration below and run `make`,

```
let &makeprg = 'make -f '.fnameescape(substitute(expand('%'), '\m_test\.cpp$', '.makefile', ''))
```

the system should run against the `ui8_c_buff_test.cpp` and execute `make -f dispatcher/unittest/ui8_c_buff.makefile`, but it is running against the `.vimrc` file where the `makeprg` is set, and I get the following result:

```
/home/sporty/.vimrc:1: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop.
```

But if I run the following command,

```
:echo 'make -f '.fnameescape(substitute(expand('%'), '\m_test\.cpp$', '.makefile', ''))
```

I get a correct result, which is:

```
make -f dispatcher/unittest/ui8_c_buff.makefile
```

So how can I get the makeprg to run against the current file instead of .vimrc?

I asked a question here: [Determining makefile based on source file name](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4503/determining-makefile-based-on-source-file-name), and got an answer, but  most of the time it does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right-hand side of `let &makeprg = ...` is evaluated only once.  If you put that command in your `.vimrc` as it is, `%`expands to `/home/sporty/.vimrc` and you get the interesting effect you describe.  You need to put it in an `autocmd`, so that it gets re-evaluated every time you open a file of the relevant type.  Also, you probably want to use the local version of `makeprg` rather than the global one:

```
autocmd  BufRead,BufNewFile  *.cpp
    \ let &l:makeprg = 'make -f '.fnameescape(substitute(expand('%:t'), '\m_test\.cpp$', '.makefile', ''))
```

You'll probably still have to solve the problem of running `make` in the correct directory.  One way to get around that is to always open your files starting from the base directory of your project.

**Edit:** As @Ben points out in comments, you can deal with changing directories automatically with another `autocmd`:

```
autocmd QuickfixCmdPre *.makefile
    \ let s:makefile = substitute(expand('%:t'), '\m_test\.cpp$', '.makefile', '') |
    \ let s:base = findfile(s:makefile, escape(expand('%:p:h'), ' ') . ';') |
    \ if s:base !=# '' |
    \     execute 'lcd ' . fnameescape(expand(s:base, '%:p:h')) |
    \ endif
```

Comment: Another way to fix "make" directory: use the QuickfixCmdPre autocmd, and search up until you find a directory containing a makefile. Change directories to that location.